# QT Eventloop and slot handle?

Tags: qt, qthread, qobject

I'm created a demo to study about QObject, QThread and QT Signal/Slot as links below

The idea is:

I created an ExtentQThread which extent from QThread and implement run() function which will loop for *loopTimeoutMsec* (set on constructor) before call exec() (which make it enter its thread event loop). I created one ExtentQThread *extQThread1* instance from main with *loopTimeoutMsec* set to *10000*.

Then I created two instances of ExtentQObject from main thread. *extQObject10* is created and moved to *extQThread1* and *extQObject11* which is not moved.

Test expectation:

- extQObject11 slot run on Main thread at around (timeout = 5000): PASSED
- extQObject10 slot run on *extQThread1*: PASSED
- extQObject10 slot run on *extQThread1* at around (*loopTimeoutMsec* = 10000): NOT PASSED

[main.cpp]

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QTimer>
#include "extentqthread.h"

long baseMSecsSinceEpoch;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    baseMSecsSinceEpoch = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();

    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << "Main thread 1" << QThread::currentThreadId();

    // === test1
    ExtentQThread extQThread1("extQThread1 created from main thread", 10000);

    ExtentQObject extQObject10("extQObject10 created from main thread then moved to extQThread1");
    extQObject10.moveToThread(&extQThread1);

    ExtentQObject extQObject11("extQObject11 created from main thread");

    extQThread1.start();

    // 1.0 to test signal of extQObject10 which is moved to extQThread1
    // and signal of extQObject11 which is not moved
    long timeout = 5000;
    QTimer::singleShot(timeout, [&extQThread1, &timeout]() {
        qDebug() << "\n==" << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << "timeout" << timeout
                 << "\n>> To test signal of extQObject10 which is moved to extQThread1 and signal of extQObject11 which is not moved"
                 << "\n>> extQThread1.isRunning()" << extQThread1.isRunning();
    });
    QTimer::singleShot(timeout, &extQObject10, &ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot);
    QTimer::singleShot(timeout, &extQObject11, &ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot);

    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << "Main thread 2" << QThread::currentThreadId();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[extentqthread.cpp]

```
#include "extentqthread.h"

extern long baseMSecsSinceEpoch;

ExtentQThread::ExtentQThread(QString name_, long loopTimeoutMsec_)
{
    name = name_;
    loopTimeoutMsec = loopTimeoutMsec_;

    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << "instance" << name
             << "loopTimeoutMsec" << loopTimeoutMsec
             << "created on thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
}

void ExtentQThread::run() {
    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << "instance" << name
             << "STARTED on thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();

    ExtentQObject extQObject("extQObject created from (" + name + ")");
    connect(this, &ExtentQThread::runFirstSlot, &extQObject, &ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot);

    if (loopTimeoutMsec < 0) {
        while(1) {};
    } else {
        QThread::msleep(loopTimeoutMsec);
    }

    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << "instance" << name
             << "before exec() on thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();

    exec();

    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << "instance" << name
             << "after exec() on thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();

    if (loopTimeoutMsec < 0) {
        while(1) {};
    } else {
        QThread::msleep(loopTimeoutMsec);
    }

    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << "instance" << name
             << "STOPPED on thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
}

void ExtentQThread::onExtentQThreadFirstSlot() {
    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << "instance" << name
             << "run on thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();

    Q_EMIT runFirstSlot();
}
```

[extentqobject.cpp]

```
#include "extentqobject.h"

extern long baseMSecsSinceEpoch;

ExtentQObject::ExtentQObject(QString name_)
{
    name = name_;
    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << "instance" << name
             << "created on thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
}

void ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot() {
    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << "instance" << name
             << "run on thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
}
```

Here is the output

```
0 Main thread 1 0x7fdc8f3f3740
1 ExtentQThread::ExtentQThread(QString, long int) instance "extQThread1 created from main thread" loopTimeoutMsec 10000 created on thread 0x7fdc8f3f3740
1 ExtentQObject::ExtentQObject(QString) instance "extQObject10 created from main thread then moved to extQThread1" created on thread 0x7fdc8f3f3740
1 ExtentQObject::ExtentQObject(QString) instance "extQObject11 created from main thread" created on thread 0x7fdc8f3f3740
1 Main thread 2 0x7fdc8f3f3740
1 virtual void ExtentQThread::run() instance "extQThread1 created from main thread" STARTED on thread 0x7fdc8aa03700
1 ExtentQObject::ExtentQObject(QString) instance "extQObject created from (extQThread1 created from main thread)" created on thread 0x7fdc8aa03700

== 4754 timeout 5000 
>> To test signal of extQObject10 which is moved to extQThread1 and signal of extQObject11 which is not moved 
>> extQThread1.isRunning() true
4754 void ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot() instance "extQObject11 created from main thread" run on thread 0x7fdc8f3f3740
10001 virtual void ExtentQThread::run() instance "extQThread1 created from main thread" before exec() on thread 0x7fdc8aa03700
14756 void ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot() instance "extQObject10 created from main thread then moved to extQThread1" run on thread 0x7fdc8aa03700
```

As my understanding I would expect:
*ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot() instance "extQObject10 created from main thread then moved to extQThread1" run on thread 0x7fdc8aa03700* run at around 10000(msec) instead of 14756(msec). because the signal is emited at 5000(msec) and the exec() which enter ExtentQthread is run after 10000(msec) and it should handle *onExtentQObjectFirstSlot* then.

Could anyone give some explanation?

////

- I tried to change from QTimer::singleShot to QTimer instance it gave expected behaviour (the diff as below)

> diff --git a/main.cpp b/main.cpp
>       index ed45d23..0ebabf3 100644
>       --- a/main.cpp
>       +++ b/main.cpp
>       @@ -25,14 +25,17 @@ int main(int argc, char *argv[])

```
     // 1.0 to test signal of extQObject10 which is moved to extQThread1
     // and signal of extQObject11 which is not moved
+    QTimer timer;
+    timer.setSingleShot(true);
     long timeout = 5000;
-    QTimer::singleShot(timeout, [&extQThread1, &timeout]() {
+    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&extQThread1, &timeout]() {
         qDebug() << "\n==" << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - baseMSecsSinceEpoch << "timeout" << timeout
                  << "\n>> To test signal of extQObject10 which is moved to extQThread1 and signal of extQObject11 which is not moved"
                  << "\n>> extQThread1.isRunning()" << extQThread1.isRunning();
     });
-    QTimer::singleShot(timeout, &extQObject10, &ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot);
-    QTimer::singleShot(timeout, &extQObject11, &ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot);
+    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &extQObject10, &ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot);
+    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &extQObject11, &ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot);
+    timer.start(timeout);
```

Comment: Put the important of your code in the question, external links serve as a complement because if you break the links your question will not be useful for future readers.

Comment: edited. thanks for suggestion

Comment: It would be good if you explain what you are trying to do in the code, it is very confusing to understand without a clear explanation. I recommend you read [ask], we are not in your head, empathize with the community.

Comment: edited again. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, may be this is helpful for someone

```
QTimer::singleShot(timeout, &extQObject10, &ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot);
```

In this case QTimer::singleShot call to this overloaded function

```
QSingleShotTimer::QSingleShotTimer(int msec, Qt::TimerType timerType, const QObject *r, QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase *slotObj)
    : QObject(QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance()), hasValidReceiver(r), receiver(r), slotObj(slotObj)
{

    timerId = startTimer(msec, timerType);
    if (r && thread() != r->thread()) {
        // Avoid leaking the QSingleShotTimer instance in case the application exits before the timer fires
        connect(QCoreApplication::instance(), &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, this, &QObject::deleteLater);
        setParent(0);
        moveToThread(r->thread());
    }
}
```

this created a timer instance (let call timerA) and because *extQObject10*, which is receiver set for QTimer::singleShot, is moved to *extThread1* so timerA is moved there too.

Because QTimer extended QObject so it inherited *bool QObject::event(QEvent *e)* from QObject which handle thread change as below

```
    case QEvent::ThreadChange: {
    Q_D(QObject);
    QThreadData *threadData = d->threadData;
    QAbstractEventDispatcher *eventDispatcher = threadData->eventDispatcher.load();
    if (eventDispatcher) {
        QList<QAbstractEventDispatcher::TimerInfo> timers = eventDispatcher->registeredTimers(this);
        if (!timers.isEmpty()) {
            // do not to release our timer ids back to the pool (since the timer ids are moving to a new thread).
            eventDispatcher->unregisterTimers(this);
            QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "_q_reregisterTimers", Qt::QueuedConnection,
                                      Q_ARG(void*, (new QList<QAbstractEventDispatcher::TimerInfo>(timers))));
        }
    }
    break;
```

Here, *QMetaObject::invokeMethod* results a slot handle by *extQThread1*, so it is will be handled after *loopTimeoutMsec* which is set to *extQThread1*. After that, the timerA start running and will fire after the *timeout* set for it, at that time *onExtentQObjectFirstSlot* will be called on *extObject10*.

In summary, *onExtentQObjectFirstSlot* will be called on *extObject10* after *loopTimeoutMsec* (set for extQThread1) + *timeout* (set for QTimer::singleShot)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but a few advices:

- Most of the time, you don't have to override the `run` method, except if you need to control the thread activity very closely. Just create a QThread, use `moveToThread` and start the thread, that's it. You can then use the thread `started` signals or other signal/slot connection to ensure that it is executed in your thread
- `exec` will effectively run the thread event loop, and return only if the thread exists.
- You can manually run/stop the event loop using `exec` and `quit` method
- While `sleep`ing, or more generally when event loop is not running, No events will be processed or slot executed. So to execute a slot called with Invoke or via a signal from another thread, it is mandatory to call `exec` after the message is queued in the QThread event loop.

And more generally, always use signals/slots (what you did) to execute code in the proper thread, and rely when you can on higher level classes like `QtConcurrent`.

For more details, you can have a look at [Qt documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage), as well as this (a bit older) [blog article](http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/)

Comment: What I am trying to do is to "study about QObject, QThread and QT Signal/Slot". I've read quite few related article (including ones you linked) but still fell confuse so I create a demo to test what I am understanding about those thing. But the output is not as my expectation, so I asked here for some clarification if I misunderstanding something.

Comment: Looking at the code, I cannot identify why your slot is executed after ~14s, I would expect a bit more than 10. But your code is also a bit too difficult to read, compare to a MCVE, so maybe I missed something. Have you tried to change your timers value, to see the impact?

Comment: I've tried to change the *loopTimeoutMsec* set to thread also *timeout* on singleShot() but the output still given in same manner. Actually I've tried to put here minimum code to test (except header files: is it good to put all code in the question?). I've given link to code on github [here](https://github.com/memto/QObjectAndQThread), but as *eyllanesc*'s suggestion I removed it.

Comment: One thing I've tried is to change *QTimer::singleShot* to an QTimer instance then using *QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &extQObject10, &ExtentQObject::onExtentQObjectFirstSlot);* so it work as expected. but reading qtimer source [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qtimer.cpp.html#QSingleShotTimer) given that singleShot also lead to create a timer then using QObject::connect. I'm still trying to debug what is difference.

Comment: You mean that simply replacing the QTimer::singleshot with a plain QTimer, at the place in the code, provides the correct behavior? I can only think of an overhead from something executed before the Singleshot on the main thread (in the main) as reason for that. Would you put the diff between the two codes?